# Disable GWC cache emptying after style changes

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

GWC is removing all generated tiles for layer after any edit of this layers style.

Is there any possibility to turn off this feature?

I've got few changes to make on working published geoserver so if I could disable cache cleaning after changes I could make it, and preview results via WMS and after the job is done manually empty and reseed cache - this will shorten downtime of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution (or solution found me by itself)

If I'll edit style of layer cache of this layer is truncated, but only this layer - not groups of layers with this layer in it... So this is exactly what I need... I hope this is not a BUG and noone will reapir it :)

Posting answer maybe someone will find it usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loud here.

I am afraid this behavior cannot be changed as it is part of the inner integration code between GS and GWC, th

I will think more about it and then I'll let you know.

Simone.

Comment: Thanx 4 feedback - I think this could be usefull feature that allow to apply changes during work-time and only thing you have to do by the night (low load time) is to rebuild cache :)

Comment: I've found some feature.. If you'll edit style of layer cache of this layer is truncated, but only this layer - not groups of layers with this layer in it... So this is exactly what I need... I hope this is not a BUG and noone will reapir it :)